# react native visual studio build: Cannot open included file: 'folly/portability/Config.h': No such file or directory

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, folly

I am developing a windows application with react native. Everything worked fine, but all of a sudden, building and running the application with `npx react-native run-windows` failed with a `Building Solution failed` error. So I tried to build the solution in VS 2019 separatly, and as expected the build failed too. I get about 140 error messages saying `Cannot open included file: 'folly/portability/Config.h': No such file or directory`. Strange thing is, that just happened out of nowhere, everything worked fine an hour ago and I didnt changed anything.
So I tried the following things, of which none worked:

- Cleaning and Rebuilding the Solution
- Restarting visual studio and the pc
- updating visual studio
- deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders
- unchecking and re-checkin the `Folly` option in the Solution Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running `npx react-native-windows-init --overwrite` in the react native project folder. I then imported my C# project into the solution, and build it without any errors. When building the solution the first time, you can see a log saying something like 'extracting folly from facebook to node_modules'. Perhaps vs crashed the time I first build the solution.